# Sorting a selection in d3.js disturbs the data-join

Tags: d3.js

When I reorder a selection of paths in d3 with selection.sort(), the data-join is disturbed and my paths get reassigned to the wrong data objects.

I only want to reorder the paths so that some end up on top of others (as in z-index). I do not want to reassign data objects from one path to another.

How can I reorder the paths without disturbing the data-join?

```
_friends.selectAll('path').sort(function(a, b){
  return d3.ascending(a.Q, b.Q);
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like you need to specify a [*key* function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data). This allows you to bind data by an arbitrary key, rather than relying on the default, which is to use the datum's position in the array i.e. the order (which in your case may change).

If you don't already have a unique key for each datum, you can always just generate them at load time:

```
var id = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) data[i].id = id++;
```

If you create any new data you can continue to increment `id` to get a new, unique ID.

Then, for data binding you can do:

```
.data(data, function(d) { return d.id; })
```

Comment: See also the [tutorial on object constancy](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/), which discusses key functions.