# Sort data for d3.js path

Tags: svg, path, d3.js

I want to create a path with d3.js that has dates for the x-axis. This is working perfectly, but my problem is, that my json-object isn't sorted so that the path is not correct:
[image]

I couldn't find a function that sorts my data - or do I have to write one by my own? If yes, I would try it but if there is another possibility.. ;)

```
            var line = d3.svg.line()
                .interpolate("linear")
                .x(function(d) { return x(d.finished_at); })
                .y(function(d) { return y(d.result); });

            svg.selectAll("path")
                .data(data)
            .enter().append("path")
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", line(data));
```

Has anyone an idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at d3.ascending?
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_ascending

or you can do this...

[Sorting a selection in d3.js disturbs the data-join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496393/sorting-a-selection-in-d3-js-disturbs-the-data-join)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I didnt got the sense before ;) Now I just wrote a function at the beginning that sorts very easiliy:  `data.sort(function(a, b){  return d3.ascending(a.finished_at, b.finished_at);  });`

Comment: Yeah...when playing with d3.js it took me a few days to understand the API too.